# After first around AutoScroll timeout problem

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview

I have a problem with an auto scroll, the first round works correctly, the images change every 10 seconds without a problem, after the last image passes and the first one starts again, the problem begins, it does not respect times and white screens appear

after the first lap, it blinks and does not respect the 10 second time

Function AutoScroll run

```
private fun startAutoScroll() {
    timer = Timer()
    var currentIndex = 0 // Index of the current image
    val imagePaths = downloadedImagePaths.filter { it.endsWith(".jpg") || it.endsWith(".jpeg") || it.endsWith(".png") }

    // Define a runnable to handle the auto scroll
    val autoScrollRunnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (imagePaths.isNotEmpty()) {
                val nextPage = (currentIndex + 1) % imagePaths.size
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(nextPage, true)
                currentIndex = nextPage // Update the current index
                viewPager.postDelayed(this, 10000) // 10 seconds delay
            }
        }
    }

    // Start the auto scroll runnable
    viewPager.postDelayed(autoScrollRunnable, 0)
}
```